# Enforcing same generics type in a class using generics

Tags: java, generics

The following example is taken from [GenericsFAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ002):

```
class Pair<X,Y>  { 
    private X first;
    private Y second;

    public Pair(X a1, Y a2) {
      first  = a1;
      second = a2;
    }
    public X getFirst()  { return first; }
    public Y getSecond() { return second; }
    public void setFirst(X arg)  { first = arg; }
    public void setSecond(Y arg) { second = arg; }
}
```

Question: I wanted to enforce `X` and `Y` should be of same type. Example `Pair<Integer,Integer>` is correct but `Pair<Integer, String>` should not be accepted. Is it possible to achieve this through Generics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
class Pair<X> {
```

And change all `Y` to `X`.

Comment: When we use `class Pair<X>` then will it possible to write Pair<Integer, Integer> or `Pair<Integer>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider something like this?

```
class LikePair<Z> extends Pair<Z,Z> {

    public LikePair(Z a, Z b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

}
```

That way you get to keep the (potentially very useful) Pair class whilst also enforcing your 'likeness' constraint were needed.

As a matter of programming style I'd make Pair (and LikePair) immutable (final fields, no setters).  Would also be good to implement equals(), hashCode(), toString(), etc.